# What algorithms did Dijkstra develop?

Tags: algorithm, computer-science, terminology, dijkstra

I recently asked a question about one of the Dijkstra’s algorithms ([shunting-yard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm)). But almost everyone thought "Dijkstra's algorithm" meant his shortest path algorithm.

What other algorithms has Dijkstra developed?

Comment: Should make this community wiki before it gets closed. Also, add your algorithm as an answer rather than part of the question.

Comment: a resource that could be used for this http://userweb.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/welcome.html

Comment: Almost everyone thought you were talking about the shortest path algorithm because that is the one that's called Dijkstra's algorithm. All the other ones have real names.

Comment: What do you think about changing the subject to "What algorithms did Dijkstra discover?"

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### Algorithms by [Edsger W. Dijkstra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edsger_Dijkstra)

1. [Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm)
2. [Shunting-yard algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm)
3. [Banker's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banker's_algorithm)
4. [Smooth Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothsort)
5. [Dijkstra-Scholten algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra-Scholten_algorithm)

Comment: It seams pretty clear to me, that this is the right answer. How can it be 'unanswerable'?

Comment: The question was written rather poorly at first. @Thomas (Good call on making wiki, Marc, already had one under 2k user add to it.)